# How do you include sass generated css map file in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sass

In wordpress, I'm able to load the css file generated from the sass files, but how do you also include the css.map file?

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'sass-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/sass-styles.css' );
// but how about sass-styles.css.map
```